# Geotools access attribute table on Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, attribute-table, geotools

I want to access the attribute table of a `SimpleFeatureCollection` I have created within a WPS process by clipping it out of a Vectorlayer stored on Geoserver.

How can this be done? Is using an `AttributeDescriptor` the right approach? It's quite difficult to google and I can't find answers on this one.

Edit:
I tried it like this (my `SimpleFeatureCollection` is called `test`):

```
SimpleFeatureType type = test.getSchema();
AttributeDescriptor attributeDescriptor = type.getDescriptor(0); // just fixed index 0 for testing purpose
attributeDescriptor.getName();
```

Obvously the last line would need to get printed out in order to look at the result ..

But then I realized that this is probably a very wrong approach to get the attribute table.

Comment: please make sure to show us what you have already tried

Comment: I edited the question. I don't really know what to show since I found nothing explicit on how to access the attribute table. Do you have any link for me?

Comment: show us the shortest code that shows what you are trying to do that still gives the issue, in this case we need to see the featurecollection, and what you are trying to do to it.

Comment: I have no code that I can really show to you because I haven't found any tutorial or sample code on how to access the values stored in the attribute table of the vectorlayer. I have a modified version of the gs:clip WPS process which I call that returns a SimpleFeatureCollection. Right now I am iterating through the SimpleFeatureCollection using a SimpleFeatureIterator and retriev the area of each feature. I know want to parallel be able to access the values for this specific feature to comine this to a more meaningful output than just areas and maybe an index for the area ...

Comment: I don't know what part of the question would need a code sample because it is a more general question and I was hoping to get a link to a sample that I can modify or learn from to fit my needs

Comment: then add that code with a comment where your issue is.

Comment: Ok well than you don't understand me and the issue that I have no starting point to start my code. Just delete this question I will try to google some more or ask somewhere else ..

Comment: in your previous comment you describe your process - please put that code into the question to show us what you have tried so far